Title: How to visualize hierarchical data with nested pie charts in Python?
I have hierarchical data that I would like to visualize using nested pie charts in Python. The data consists of Phylum, Genus, and Species levels, and I want to create a nested pie chart where each level represents a ring in the chart.
I have already attempted to implement this using Matplotlib, but I'm facing challenges in filtering and displaying only specific portions of the nested pie charts based on the abundance of certain categories. Specifically, I want to:
Display all Phylum initially.
Filter and display only the Genera related to a specific Phylum (e.g., Firmicutes).
Filter and display only the Species related to a specific Genus (e.g., Bacillus).
I've tried to modify the code based on suggestions I found online, but I'm not getting the desired output.
Could someone please provide guidance or a code example on how to achieve this visualization using Python and Matplotlib?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

# Read the Excel file
TissueS35_Analysis_Report = pd.read_excel("TissueS35_Analysis_Report.xlsx", sheet_name="Species")

# Select only the 'Phylum', 'Genus', and 'Species' columns
selected_columns = TissueS35_Analysis_Report[['Phylum', 'Genus', 'Species', 'Absolute Count']]

# Group by Phylum, Genus, and Species and sum the counts
grouped_data = selected_columns.groupby(['Phylum', 'Genus', 'Species']).sum().reset_index()

# Function to generate nested pie chart data
def nested_pie(df):
    outd = {}
    for level in range(3):
        if level == 0:
            gb = df.groupby('Phylum', sort=False).sum()
        elif level == 1:
            gb = df.groupby(['Phylum', 'Genus'], sort=False).sum()
        else:
            gb = df.groupby(['Phylum', 'Genus', 'Species'], sort=False).sum()
        outd[level] = {'names': gb.index.get_level_values(level).tolist(), 'values': gb['Absolute Count'].values}
    return outd

# Generate nested pie chart data
outd = nested_pie(grouped_data)

# Plot nested donut pie chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot Species level (Outermost ring)
sizes = outd[2]['values']
species_colors = plt.cm.tab20c.colors
species_labels = outd[2]['names']
ax.pie(sizes, radius=1, colors=species_colors, labels=species_labels, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='w'))

# Plot Genus level (Middle ring)
sizes = outd[1]['values']
genus_colors = plt.cm.tab20b.colors
genus_labels = outd[1]['names']
ax.pie(sizes, radius=0.7, colors=genus_colors, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='w'))

# Plot Phylum level (Innermost ring)
sizes = outd[0]['values']
phylum_colors = plt.cm.tab20.colors
phylum_labels = outd[0]['names']
ax.pie(sizes, radius=0.4, colors=phylum_colors, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3, edgecolor='w'))

# Create legend for Phylum level
legend_handles = [Patch(color=color, label=label) for color, label in zip(phylum_colors, phylum_labels)]
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), title='Phylum')

ax.set(aspect="equal")
plt.show()


small data refernce is  as follow 
Phylum             Genus         Species  Absolute Count
168  Proteobacteria       Pseudomonas    Unclassified           73745
152  Proteobacteria        Klebsiella    Unclassified           10777
190  Proteobacteria      Unclassified    Unclassified            4932
132  Proteobacteria   Chromobacterium    Unclassified            1840
84       Firmicutes    Lysinibacillus  boronitolerans            1780
104      Firmicutes         Weissella       ghanensis            1101
10   Actinobacteria   Corynebacterium    Unclassified             703
138  Proteobacteria       Cupriavidus        gilardii             586
93       Firmicutes    Staphylococcus    Unclassified             568
183  Proteobacteria  Stenotrophomonas      geniculata             542
Selection deleted

If possible, how can i do for overlay image as given below, I will be thankful for this help, Regards


I updated my answer with the second type of pie chart

One way of doing this would be to define a function that creates the nested pie chart:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

data = {
    'Phylum': ['Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Firmicutes', 'Actinobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Proteobacteria'],
    'Genus': ['Pseudomonas', 'Klebsiella', 'Unclassified', 'Chromobacterium',
              'Lysinibacillus', 'Weissella', 'Corynebacterium', 'Cupriavidus',
              'Staphylococcus', 'Stenotrophomonas'],
    'Species': ['Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified',
                'boronitolerans', 'ghanensis', 'Unclassified', 'gilardii',
                'Unclassified', 'geniculata'],
    'Absolute Count': [73745, 10777, 4932, 1840, 1780, 1101, 703, 586, 568, 542]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def create_nested_pie(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    size = 0.3
    phylum_counts = df.groupby('Phylum')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    phylum_labels = phylum_counts.index.tolist()
    ax.pie(phylum_counts, labels=phylum_labels, radius=1, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

    firmicutes_genus_counts = df[df['Phylum'] == 'Firmicutes'].groupby('Genus')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    firmicutes_genus_labels = firmicutes_genus_counts.index.tolist()
    ax.pie(firmicutes_genus_counts, labels=firmicutes_genus_labels, radius=1-size, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'),
           labeldistance=0.7)

    lysinibacillus_species_counts = df[(df['Phylum'] == 'Firmicutes') & (df['Genus'] == 'Lysinibacillus')].groupby('Species')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    lysinibacillus_species_labels = lysinibacillus_species_counts.index.tolist()
    ax.pie(lysinibacillus_species_counts, labels=lysinibacillus_species_labels, radius=1-2*size, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'),
           labeldistance=0.4)

    plt.show()

create_nested_pie(df)

Which give you:

Update: filtering
If your data i large, then filtering to show specific labels can be done by modifying the function slightly:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

data = {
    'Phylum': ['Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Firmicutes', 'Actinobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Proteobacteria'],
    'Genus': ['Pseudomonas', 'Klebsiella', 'Unclassified', 'Chromobacterium',
              'Lysinibacillus', 'Weissella', 'Corynebacterium', 'Cupriavidus',
              'Staphylococcus', 'Stenotrophomonas'],
    'Species': ['Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified',
                'boronitolerans', 'ghanensis', 'Unclassified', 'gilardii',
                'Unclassified', 'geniculata'],
    'Absolute Count': [73745, 10777, 4932, 1840, 1780, 1101, 703, 586, 568, 542]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def create_filtered_nested_pie(df, phylum_filter=None, genus_filter=None, species_filter=None):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    size = 0.3
    
    if phylum_filter is not None:
        df = df[df['Phylum'].isin(phylum_filter)]
    phylum_counts = df.groupby('Phylum')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    ax.pie(phylum_counts, labels=phylum_counts.index.tolist(), radius=1, 
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

    if genus_filter is not None:
        df_genus = df[df['Genus'].isin(genus_filter)]
    else:
        df_genus = df
    genus_counts = df_genus.groupby('Genus')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    ax.pie(genus_counts, labels=genus_counts.index.tolist(), radius=1-size, 
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labeldistance=0.7)

    if species_filter is not None:
        df_species = df_genus[df_genus['Species'].isin(species_filter)]
    else:
        df_species = df_genus
    species_counts = df_species.groupby('Species')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    ax.pie(species_counts, labels=species_counts.index.tolist(), radius=1-2*size, 
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labeldistance=0.4)

    plt.show()

create_filtered_nested_pie(df, 
                           phylum_filter=['Proteobacteria', 'Firmicutes'],
                           genus_filter=['Pseudomonas', 'Lysinibacillus'],
                           species_filter=['boronitolerans', 'Unclassified'])


wich gives

To get a proportional pie chart and eliminate everything that is not filtered (turning then transparent), I modified my function slightly to compute the proportion occupied and "hide" what is not filtered:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Phylum': ['Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Firmicutes', 'Actinobacteria', 'Proteobacteria',
               'Firmicutes', 'Proteobacteria'],
    'Genus': ['Pseudomonas', 'Klebsiella', 'Unclassified', 'Chromobacterium',
              'Lysinibacillus', 'Weissella', 'Corynebacterium', 'Cupriavidus',
              'Staphylococcus', 'Stenotrophomonas'],
    'Species': ['Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified', 'Unclassified',
                'boronitolerans', 'ghanensis', 'Unclassified', 'gilardii',
                'Unclassified', 'geniculata'],
    'Absolute Count': [3745, 10777, 4932, 1840, 1780, 1101, 703, 586, 568, 542]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def create_selective_label_pie(df, phylum_filter=None, genus_filter=None, species_filter=None):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    size = 0.3

    total_phylum_counts = df.groupby('Phylum')['Absolute Count'].sum()
    phylum_colors = ['blue' if phylum in phylum_filter else 'none' for phylum in total_phylum_counts.index]
    phylum_labels = [phylum if phylum in phylum_filter else "" for phylum in total_phylum_counts.index]
    ax.pie(total_phylum_counts, labels=phylum_labels, colors=phylum_colors, radius=1,
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

    total_genus_counts = df.groupby(['Phylum', 'Genus'])['Absolute Count'].sum()
    genus_colors = ['green' if (phylum in phylum_filter and genus in genus_filter) else 'none' 
                    for (phylum, genus) in total_genus_counts.index]
    genus_labels = [genus if (phylum in phylum_filter and genus in genus_filter) else ""
                    for (phylum, genus) in total_genus_counts.index]
    ax.pie(total_genus_counts, labels=genus_labels, colors=genus_colors, radius=1-size,
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labeldistance=0.7)

    total_species_counts = df.groupby(['Phylum', 'Genus', 'Species'])['Absolute Count'].sum()
    species_colors = ['red' if (phylum in phylum_filter and genus in genus_filter and species in species_filter) else 'none'
                      for (phylum, genus, species) in total_species_counts.index]
    species_labels = [species if (phylum in phylum_filter and genus in genus_filter and species in species_filter) else ""
                      for (phylum, genus, species) in total_species_counts.index]
    ax.pie(total_species_counts, labels=species_labels, colors=species_colors, radius=1-2*size,
           wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'), labeldistance=0.4)

    plt.title('Pie Chart with Selective Labels and Transparency')
    plt.show()

create_selective_label_pie(df, 
                           phylum_filter=['Firmicutes'],
                           genus_filter=['Weissella'],
                           species_filter=['boronitolerans'])

which gives (a ridiculous example, but illustrative)

THis

create_selective_label_pie(df, 
                           phylum_filter=['Proteobacteria', 'Firmicutes'],
                           genus_filter=['Lysinibacillus'],
                           species_filter=['boronitolerans'])

would give

For color variations, you'll have to do something on your own.

Hi, thank you for your reply. In another way, I want to ask if it's possible to display only selected labels. If you see my original plot, many labels are appearing, making it look messy. Specifically, I would like to label 'Firmicutes - Lysinibacillus-boronitolerans' in the plot.

Updated my answer with a filter

Unfortunately, your "wish" in the last image was beyong my knowledge of matplotlib.

Thank u very much, this itself is enough for me

Glad it helped. Make sure to mark the answer as accepted so it dispapears from the list of unanswered questions. Happy coding!

Bu I want to know, is it not possible to draw like i gave overlay image the second image?

That is what I said I didn't really know how to do.

I just had an idea. Let med test it

Sorry, to disturbe u again, but could  u please do like, inside whole circle with phylum, like  firmicutes and proteobacteria, then second outer layer overlay Lysinibacillus and then overlay with third outer layer boronitolerans, and thanks for your effort, i really appreciate
